# Ghematria in Python: hebrew letters to numbers and sum

Tags: python, hebrew

I'd like to write a small program in Python that takes a hebrew text, converts each letter into its ghematria numbers, **sum the numbers in each word**, then prints the words as numbers.

to start off I was thinking to set the aleph beth variables,
like:

```
א=1
ב=2
ג=3
ד=4
```

and so on...

Keep in mind that since Hebrew letters are [strong right-to-left characters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Bidirectional_Character_Types), everything starts showing up right-to-left after one. Those assignments just *look* backward; they [really are valid](http://ideone.com/bbqwDj) in Python 3.

Now that I have set the variables I was wondering how could I get the numbers for all the words from a txt file (unicode 8 of course)..
any help for a noob?

Comment: "Keep in mind that since we are using hebrew the value of the variable is set at the LEFT of the = sign" <- I'm not sure I follow what you are doing there. Keep in mind we're using Python?

Comment: if you want to set a variable using a hebrew letter like aleph=1 it is displayed 
as 1=א...

Comment: I understood this, but how is this relevant to the replacement and summing you want to achieve?

Comment: @timgeb It is not relevant, he just wanted to ensure that you did not think that he was setting the variable `1` to the value `א` rather than the variable `א' to the value `1` which is what he meant

Comment: I am asking how to do it.. I set the variables (step 1) but I am wondering how to extract each letter from a word, convert it to number and sum it with all the other letters of the word.

Answer (score 2):

> Keep in mind that since we are using hebrew the value of the variable is set at the LEFT of the = sign... and not at the right...

Python doesn't care. `1 = א` won't work anway as you are trying to assign a value to an `int`.

The other way around also won't be a pleasure to work with. Unicode identifiers are supported only by Python 3, but I wouldn't go down that road.

What I would do is have a dictionary with letters as keys and numbers as values.

Then simply read the text file, convert each letter to its number and sum.

**EDIT** Something of this sort. 
Note that I only have 3 letters in the dictionary because I'm lazy, and that I'm 
using the dictionary's `get()` method so I won't get `KeyError` on spaces, new lines and punctuation marks.

```
vals = {'א': 1,
        'ב': 2,
        'ג': 3}

with open(path_to_file, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    sum = 0
    for letter in text:
        sum += vals.get(letter, 0)

print(sum)
```

Comment: very interesting. I'll try this and report.
Thanks much indeed

Comment: Is your dictionary broken? `{'1 :'א,` is how it reads to me. Or is that just unicode barfing?

Comment: @WayneWerner: The Hebrew letter's right-to-leftness sort of gets inherited by the following text. [The details are complicated.](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/)

Comment: @WayneWerner It should be ok when copy and pasting to an IDE or text editor, it's just RTL at its best...

Comment: So this is *actually* `{'hebrew letter': 1,...`? RTL sure makes my brain hurt :-\